# Angular provide formcontrols from child-class to formgroup of parent class

Tags: angular

given following Code:

```js
export type FormGroupModel<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: AbstractControl | FormGroup;
};
@Directive()
export class Base<T> {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
  this.form = new FormGroup(this.getFormModel())
}
  abstract getFormModel(): FormGroupModel<F>;
}


interface IModel {
 id: number;
 name: string;
}

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent extends Base<IModel> {

 getFormModel(): FormGroupModel<IModel> {
 return {
  id: new FormControl(null),
  name: new FormControl(null)
 }
 }
}
```

What I do not understand is, when in `form` a value is patched e.g. `form.patchValue({id: null, name: 'test'})` the value is accessible in the form but not when `someComponent.getFormModel().name.value` is accessed.

My unit test looks like this

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
    let component: SomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [SomeComponent],
        imports: [],
      }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });


      it('should return value', () => {
        const testVal: string = 'test';
        const val = {
          id: 10,
          name: testVal
        };

        component.form.patchValue(val);

        expect(component.getFormModel().name.value).toEqual(testVal);
      });
});
```

and it does fail because `component.getFormModel().name.value` is `null` (the initial value).

Instead of  `this.form = new FormGroup(this.getFormModel())`, I also tried:

```js
 this.form = new FormGroup({});
for (const key in this.getFormModel()) {
 this.form.addControl(key, this.getFormModel()[key])
}
```

What am I missing?

For better understandability I prepared an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-anzztt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
after clicking on patchValue the values should still be the same

Comment: Try with `component.form.value.name` instead

Comment: Did you try someComponent.getFormModel().get('name of you control').value ?

Comment: @temp_user this will of course work, but is not what I want as there's not type safety (at least for Angular <14)

Comment: @SergioRinaudo the get() method is nto available on getFormModel as it does not return a FormGroup

Comment: @Mikelgo why do you care about type safety in your tests, you're supposed to mock your data anyways

Answer (score 0):

getFormModel() would be more accurately called createFormModel() because it always creates new FormControls.
In the test a FormGroup is created (from the constructor of Base), to access it you should access the component property 'form'.  The use of getFormModel() is creating new FormControls which have a null value.

```js
 it('should return value', () => {
        const testVal: string = 'test';
        const val = {
          id: 10,
          name: testVal
        };

        component.form.patchValue(val);
        // This accesses the component property form
        expect(component.form.get('name').value).toEqual(testVal);
        // This creates new FormControls
        expect(component.getFormModel('name').value).toEqual(null);
      });
```

To answer your question what's happening here:

```js
for (const key in this.getFormModel()) {
 this.form = new FormGroup({});
 this.form.addControl(key, this.getFormModel()[key])
}
```

The first line is creating an object of two empty FormControls with keys 'id' and 'name'.
The for-loop then iterates with the 'id' key. In the loop a new (empty) FormGroup is assigned to the component property form.
This new FormGroup then has a control added with the key value being the current loop key ('id'), now the value is another call to getFormModel() which creates another new object of the same values as the first line of the loop. This is how you can use the loop key value to access it without problems. The key's are the same. On the next loop iteration the form is rest to an empty object.

After the for-loop your component property form will have a FormGroup with one control (from the second iteration of the loop), which will be of 'name' with a null value.

The critical point here is that you're creating new objects when you want to be referencing existing ones.

```js
// These two code blocks have the same result
this.form = new FormGroup({});
for (const key in this.getFormModel()) {
 this.form.addControl(key, this.getFormModel()[key])
}
// Use this one for fewer redundant function calls
this.form = new FormGroup(this.getFormModel())
```